# OData WebAPI 2.2 Post method Example

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am in creation of webapi odata service. I have a post method named "Validate" in my controller named "User" as below:

```
    public class UserController : ODataController
        {

               [HttpPost]
                public HttpResponseMessage Post(LoginEntityDto objLogin)
                {
                    //mylogin 

                }
        }

    //Custom class
    public class LoginEntityDto
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
        }
```

I am inputting this post method with the below JSON Format

```
{
  "username": "C201566",
  "password" : "pwd"

}
```

I am using the content-type : application / json

but in my post method the input objLogin is always **null**
Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

OData/Webapi doesn't support post a complex type in this way, why not make it as an entity type by define the key and entityset.

```
 [key]
 username {get;set;}

 ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
 builder.EntitySet<LoginEntityDto>("LoginEntityDto");
```

or you can use action to post this complex type as parameter.
FYI: http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-07-action-parameter-support

Comment: i dont want the the class to be an entity type since i am not going to create table for it. its just a custom class

Comment: so why not try post to a function

Comment: I tried like this var getJoinDetailsPost = modelBuilder.Function("UpdateUser");          getJoinDetailsPost.Parameter<Entities.LoginEntityDto>("login");  and created a function like this [HttpPost]
        [EnableQuery]
        [ODataRoute("GetOLAFDataPost")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetOLAFDataPost([FromBody] Entities.LoginEntityDto login)
        {  //mycode logic }
but still the value is null :(

Comment: In Odata spec, function should be get, and won't change the service data, in your scenario, post should use action, the parameter type is `ODataActionParameters` http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-07-action-parameter-support

Comment: @user2256194 You also need to add LoginEntityDto as a complex type to the EDM for your GetOLAFDataPost method to work, e.g. modelBuilder.AddComplexType(typeof (LoginEntityDto)) - Without this the framework doesn't know how to handle your DTO.